# create Blog with CakePhp but issue with role of users?

Tags: php, cakephp, model-view-controller, blogs, role

when i register with new user its always put null value in database.
also topic to visible/ hide  to admin and user.Please Solve it
here is code:

```
public function add() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $this->User->create();
        $this->request->data['User']['password'] = AuthComponent::password($this->request->data['User']['password']);
        $this->request->data['User']['role'] === '1';
        if ($this->User->save($this->request->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user has been saved.'));
            return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This does not set 'role' to 1.

```
$this->request->data['User']['role'] === '1';
```

You need this:

```
$this->request->data['User']['role'] = 1;
```

EDIT:

$this->Auth->user('role') should be equal to your admin role. I hope it is 1 in your coding.

```
<?php if($this->Auth->user('role') == 1  || $topic['Topic']['visible'] == 1): ?>
  /* Your Topic */
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: thank you but i have one more problem i set a visibility. 1 for visible and 2 for hidden but admin also didnt see the topics also set conditions for admin to see visible {<?php if(AuthComponent::user('role')  == 1 || !AuthComponent::user()) :?>
    <?php if($topic['Topic']['visible'] == 2):?> }